# request method showing 403 error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

app.post("/",function(req,res){
// console.log(req.body.crypto);

```
request("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/all?crypto=BTC&fiat=USD,EUR",function(error,response,body){
    console.error('error:', error);
    console.log(response.statusCode);

});
```

Comment: The [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) has been deprecated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/):

> All requests to our API must be authenticated with your public key.
>
> First register an account.
>
> Then choose one of our plans from the plans page.
>
> Finally get your public key from the main dashboard.

You're not passing any key in your request.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error with 403 (Forbidden) status code because the API you are trying to use requires an API key. You can see it in their API documentation.

[image: API docs]

What you should do is following the steps mentioned in API documentation and get a API key. Then you should to use this API key as `x-ba-key` header for your future requests like below:

[image: Postman image]

I suggest you to use [axious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package to make your API calls since [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module is deprecated and they will not support future issues and versions. Install axios package using `npm install axios` command and then import it to your application file. Then make a request to the endpoint with your API key like this:

```
const options = {
    headers: { 'x-ba-key': 'yourAPIKey' }
};

axios.get('https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/all?crypto=BTC&fiat=USD,EUR', options)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```